# Trouble accessing components in other C# forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, label, tabcontrol

I have a main form that includes TabControl. New forms are added as tabs in TabControl. I have trouble changing current active tab or closing tabs from forms that are not the form with TabControl. All components that i'm trying to access are Public.

Here is the code i used to change tabs:

```
Main mainForm = new Main();
mainForm.tcMain.SelectTab(mainForm.tpHome);
```

It doesn't work even if i try it to change it to index of the first tab, 0.

I also have a Label in Main form that i'm trying to change from other forms like this:

```
Main mainForm = new Main();
mainForm.labelStatus.Text = "Refreshed";
```

If it would be of any help, this is how the form i'm trying to access main form from is called

```
Table tableForm = new Table();
tableForm.TopLevel = false;
TabPage tableTab = new TabPage(tableForm.Text);
tcMain.TabPages.Add(tableTab);
tableForm.panelTable.Parent = tableTab;
tableForm.Parent = tableTab;
tcMain.SelectTab(tableTab);
tableForm.Show();
```

Comment: Just create a property to store the Main `Form` and a constructor for Table accepting `Form` as a parameter and pass your Main `Form` to it. Then you will change current tab through that property

Comment: Wait, For every property you want to change you are creating a new Instance of `Main`?? No wonder they don't change.

Comment: I'm trying to create a property to store Main but i'm kind of lost. And yes, i was creating a new instance of Main. I didn't know how else to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new Instance of `Main` for every property you modify, you are actually creating that many windows forms, and they have no relation to each other, They just sit in memory until they are shown to the user. What you need is a reference to the actual Main form created at the start of the application. For that, have the controls that you want to modify as public and something like below will do.

**Main Class Global :**

```
static public Main instance;
```

Main Class **Main_Load()** method :

```
instance = this;
```

In all your other forms just access main form instance like `Main.instance`. So this

```
Main mainForm = new Main();
mainForm.labelStatus.Text = "Refreshed";
```

will become

```
Main.instance.labelStatus.Text = "Refreshed";
```

The important thing here will be to set the access modifiers of all the controls you want to modify in the Main form to `public`.